# update listadapter dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Here is my arrayAdapter where I have two textfields, "imgen" and "txtTitle". Currently I set the following text to the "imgen" textView from the arrayAdapter

```
holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(weather.getBuyingRate()));
```

Below is the adapter.

```
package com.example.mainactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    Weather data[] = null;



    public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Weather[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgen);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Weather weather = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.getName());
        holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(weather.getBuyingRate()));

        return row;
    }

    static class WeatherHolder
    {
        TextView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

Supose that I want to change this from the main class depending on if a user has pressed a button? I want to alter between `"setText(Double.toString(weather.getBuyingRate()));"` and `setText(Double.toString(weather.getNrOfSharesInPortfolio()));` depending on what text the goButton is currently having. See comments in code below.

**Note** that this shall update the imgIcon for every element in the list.

Is there a way to get access to the "holder.imgIcon" from the MainActitivy?

Here is my MainActivity

```
package com.example.mainactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listView1;
    private Button goButton;
    private String[] listheader = {"Köp Kurs","Antal"};
    int totalElemInlist = listheader.length;
    int currentelemInList=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[]
        {
            new Weather("ABB", 56.0, 300),
            new Weather("Volvo", 89.0,500),
            new Weather("Astra Zeneca", 98.55, 50)
        };

        WeatherAdapter adapter = new WeatherAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.listview_item_row, weather_data);


        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
        listView1.addHeaderView(header);
        goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        goButton.setText(listheader[currentelemInList]);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

        goButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String buttonPressed = (String) ((Button) view).getText();
                goThroughList(buttonPressed);
                System.out.println("Button Clicked" + buttonPressed);
            }
          });
    }

    private void goThroughList(String buttonPressed){
        currentelemInList++;
        if(currentelemInList>=totalElemInlist){
            currentelemInList=0;
        }
        goButton.setText(listheader[currentelemInList]);

        if(buttonPressed == "Köp Kurs"){
            System.out.println("Köp kurs");
            //holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(weather.getBuyingRate()));
        }
        else if(buttonPressed == "Antal"){
            System.out.println("Antal");
            //holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(weather.getNrOfSharesInPortfolio()));
        }




        System.out.println(currentelemInList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a TextView imgIcon which will display either buyingRate or nrOfSharesInPortfolio. The display is switched when goButton is pressed.

```
public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather>{

    // ...

    private String buttonPressed = "Köp Kurs";

    public void setButtonPressed(String s) {
        buttonPressed = s;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // ... 

        Weather weather = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.getName());

        if(buttonPressed == "Köp Kurs"){
            holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(weather.getBuyingRate()));
        }
        else if(buttonPressed == "Antal"){
            holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(weather.getNrOfSharesInPortfolio()));
        }

        return row;
    }

    // ...
}
```

In MainActivity.onCreate(), set the goButton on click listener as:

```
goButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String buttonPressed = (String) ((Button) view).getText();
        adapter.setButtonPressed(buttonPressed);
    }
});
```